# Rename a file by replacing few characters using Batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I'm new to batch scripting and need help here.
My file name along with path is

```
C:\test\My_Test_File_20201006.txt
```

and I want to rename it as

```
C:\test\My_File_20201006.txt
```

using batch script only. I cannot use PowerShell here.

```
@echo off

set Pattern="Test_File"
set Replace="File"

Rem accepts the filename as cmd line argument
set filename=%1

Rem Update filename
set targetfile=%filename:Pattern=Replace%

Rem Rename the file
Ren %filename% %targetfile%

Exit
```

Using the above code, My file is renamed as "**File**". Tried % around the Pattern & replace variables, but no luck. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Tried all possible solutions from the StackOverflow and other tutorials, but none helped.

**Edit:**

After the proposed solution, getting a syntax error. The code is as below:

```
@echo off

set "filename=%~nx1"


echo %filename%
echo "%~dp1"
echo "%~dp1%filename:statement_=%"

ren "%~dp1%filename%" "%~dp1%filename:Test_=%"
```

I call my script from cmd line as:

```
D:/Test> C:/script/rename.bat C:\test\My_Test_File_20201006.txt
```

The echo statement correctly prints filename, directory & filename with the directory. Facing issues in rename statement.

**Output:**

```
My_Test_File_20201006.txt
"C:\test\"
"C:\test\My_Test_File_20201006.txt"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things wrong here.

1. You cannot add the quotes as part of the variable's value. It will actually use them as part of the variable. set variables to have double quotes including the variable name. For instance instead of `set Pattern="Test_File"` rather do `set "Pattern=Test_File"`
2. You never used the variables you've set `Replace` and `Pattern`
3. You either need to `enabledelayedexpansion` or use `call` to do the replacement because of the multple `%` required.

```
@echo off

set "Pattern=Test_File"
set "Replace=File"

Rem accepts the filename as cmd line argument
set "filename=%~nx1"

Rem Update filename
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ren "%~dp1%filename%" "!filename:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
```

Another method, seeing as you only replace `Test_` in your example:

```
@echo off
set "filename=%~nx1"
ren "%~dp1%filename%" "%filename:Test_=%"
```

**EDIT**

Fixing your example as per the edit.

```
@echo off

set "filename=%~nx1"


echo %filename%
echo "%~dp1"
echo "%~dp1%filename:statement_=%"

ren "%~dp1%filename%" "%filename:Test_=%"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gerhard... That was a perfect solution with a perfect explanation...:)

Comment: what if my filename consists of a complete path. for e.g. C:/test/My_File_20201006.txt

Comment: @Gerhard...The working directory of the script is different... So if I try to add the relative path of the file, I get a syntax error... Not sure why...

Comment: Unfortunately can't drag the file as per my usecase. I get syntax error for "%~dp1%filename:statement_=%" or "%~dp1!filename:%Pattern%=%Replace%!".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222662/discussion-between-r-k-and-gerhard).

Comment: Million thanks @Gerhrad... The solution was perfect...